# Suppose $x_{n}>0$ and tends to zero.We know its arithmetic mean tends to zero. I wonder which will tend to zero faster.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

In detail, $x_{n}>0$ and tends to zero, $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}$ (so 
 $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{Sn}{n}=0$). Let $T_{n}=\frac{nx_{n}}{S_{n}}.$ I think the "average" $S_n/n$ will tend to zero more slowly than $x_n$. In fact,I tried some simple examples,the limit of $T_{n}$is always zero.

So I wonder can the limit of $T_{n}$ be $\infty$? Or can the upper limit of $T_{n}$ be $\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warmup: non-zero limit.**

Suppose $(x_n)_n$ is defined by
$$
x_n = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n} &\text{ if } n \text{ is a power of two}\\
\frac{1}{2^{2^{2^n}}} &\text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
(The second condition is just to ensure positivity, for all intend and purpose we can (and will below) proceed with it at $0$).

Then
$$
S_{2^k} = \sum_{\ell=0}^k \frac{1}{2^\ell} = 2(1-1/2^{k+1})
$$
so 
$$
T_{2^k} = \frac{2^{k}x_{2^k}}{S_{2^k}} = \frac{1}{2(1-1/2^{k+1})} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \frac{1}{2} \neq 0
$$

---

**Real deal: $\infty$ limit.**

Similarly, suppose $(x_n)_n$ is defined by
$$
x_n = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} &\text{ if } n \text{ is a power of two}\\
0 &\text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
(same thing as before, one can make that positive by replacing $0$ by an insane inverse tower of exponentials, for instance).

Then
$$
S_{2^k} = \sum_{\ell=0}^k \frac{1}{2^{\ell/2}} = \frac{1-1/2^{(k+1)/2}}{1-1/\sqrt{2}}
$$
so 
$$
T_{2^k} = \frac{2^{k}x_{2^k}}{S_{2^k}} = (1-1/\sqrt{2})\cdot \frac{2^{k/2}}{1-1/2^{(k+1)/2}} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I have two questions.1.How can you construct such examples?2.Your constructed examples that the upper limit of Tn is infinity.I still wonder can the limit of Tn be infinity?

Comment: @Tree23 the idea behind these examples is basically to "pad" a sequence with a lot of very small elements, since the normalization by $n$ in $S_n/n$ then allows you to divide by $n$ even though you effectively have $o(n)$ 'contributing' elements.

Comment: For you other question... I'll think about it.

Comment: @Tree23 Here is a begnnning pf argument for which the limit cannot be $\infty$; feel free to try and make it formal using diiscrete derivation (Abel) instead. Consider the continuous case, with $x_n$ replaced by $f(x)$ (such that $\lim_{\infty} f=0$_ and $S_n$ replaced by $F(x) = \int_0^x f$. If the limit is $\infty$, we have $xf'(x)/f(x) \to \infty$, and in particular, for every $A>0$, some $x_A$ such that $f'(x)/f(x) > A/x$ for $x\geq x_A$. Integrating, that leads to $f(x) \geq \int_{x_A}^x A/t dt = A \ln(x/x_A) \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} \infty$, contradiction.

Comment: That even shows the liminf has to be 0.

Comment: Yes. Today I find a proof myself,take $x_{n_{k}}$ as the first one that is smaller than $1/k$.So $x_{n_{k}}$ is the smallest in $x_{1} \cdots x_{n_{k}}$. So $T_{n_{k}}<1.$ This shows its liminf is smaller than $1$.Thank you for your help.